# What does @Override mean in this java code?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)
>   [Java, What does @Override mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341432/java-what-does-override-mean)

I was checking out *Drools Planner* example source code and I came across code like this:

```
@Override
protected Solver createSolver() {
    XmlSolverConfigurer configurer = new XmlSolverConfigurer();
    configurer.configure(SOLVER_CONFIG);
    return configurer.buildSolver();
}

protected Solver createSolverByApi() {
    // Not recommended! It is highly recommended to use XmlSolverConfigurer with an XML configuration instead.
    SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig();

    solverConfig.setSolutionClass(NQueens.class);
    .....TRUNCATED....
    solverPhaseConfigList.add(localSearchSolverPhaseConfig);
    solverConfig.setSolverPhaseConfigList(solverPhaseConfigList);
    return solverConfig.buildSolver();
}
```

As far as I understand `createSolver()` and `createSolverByApi()` are supposed to return Solver objects when you explicitly call them.

What does the `@Override` mean here? What is the general meaning of the **@** term?

---

**EDIT:** My very bad; I inadvertently duplicated [What does @Override mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341432/java-what-does-override-mean)

Comment: At least make *some* attempt at reading the documentation... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `@` is [Java Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html).

The `@Override` means that the method is overriding the parent class (in this case `createSolver`).

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) states for `@Override`:

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method
>   declaration in a superclass.

This annotation is useful for compile-time checking to verify that the method you're overriding is valid (overridden correctly).

Comment: So, can a method be overridden at all without this? What happens if this is excluded when a method is intended to overwrite another?

Comment: It can be overridden without the annotation. It just helps developers know that there is a parent class method that has been overridden by a child class.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Java tutorial about annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html), and there the 'Annotations used by the compiler' section. A quick copy-paste from the relevant part

> @Override—the @Override annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass (overriding methods will be discussed in the the lesson titled "Interfaces and Inheritance").

Answer (score 2):

This is called an `Annotation`. It is actually not compiled into special code, but it helps avoiding errors: essentially, it indicates that the method *overrides* a method of a `superclass`. Not having this annotation can cause *warnings*, having this annotation but no superclass that has a method with the same annotation is even an *error*.

This avoids refactoring errors: if the method in the `superclass` is renamed, and the override not, then it will become an error.

Comment: No special meaning to the compiler ... how can it generate a compile error if the compiler does not assign a special meaning to it. See my answer. It is discussed in the 'Annotations used by the compiler' section, so it certainly has special meaning to the compiler

Comment: As in: no run time retention AFAIK.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse good explanation so +1 also I have edited your answer for correct spelling

Answer (score 0):

This is java annotation , in your case you would use `@Override` above a method to be sure that you are overriding a super class method , if you use it and the method is not in the super class because you type it name wrong for example  an error will occur at compile time .

Answer (score 0):

I want to add this : 
declared in a superClass or method declared in an interface (since Java 6)

Comment: No, annotation got introduced since Java 5. `@Override` got introduced since Java 5 (by Joshua Bloch).

Comment: declared in a superClass since java 5

and declared in interface since java6