# Events in ontology

Tags: events, ontology, protege

I want to implement events to ontology. For example by adding an individual to one class it's added to another class. Following the instructions in [ProtegeOWL_API_Advanced_Topics](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/ProtegeOWL_API_Advanced_Topics) I wrote this:

```
      JenaOWLModel model=ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModel();
      OWLNamedClass c1= model.createOWLNamedClass("A");
      OWLNamedClass c2= model.createOWLNamedClass("B");
      c1.addClassListener( new ClassAdapter(){
       public void instaneAdded(RDFSClass c1,RDFSClass c2,RDFResource instance) {
         String s= instance.getName();
         c2.createInstance(s);
       }
       });
```

Isn't it right way? Because it doesn't work in protege.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work in Protégé"?  Protege is a OWL ontology editor;  it's not a Java compiler.   You need to describe what you're doing in more detail, along with what you _expected_ to happen, and what's _actually_ happening.

Comment: I mean when I import the .owl file I created in my java code to protege and I add an individual to "A" class it doesn't add to the "B" class.

Comment: Are you writing a stand alone application?  A Protege plugin?  There's a _whole_ lot that you haven't told us.  Should `instaneAdded` be `instanceAdded` (note the `c`)?  If you use an `@Override` annotation, you'd get an error about trying to override a not-previously-defined method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet that in your new class adapter, you meant to define a method `instanceAdded`, not `instaneAdded` (note the `c` in the former).  If you follow best practices and use the `@Override` annotation, you would have gotten an error about not being able to override a method that wasn't previously defined.

```java
  public void instaneAdded(RDFSClass c,RDFSClass c2,RDFResource instance) {
              ************
```

The advice to add `@Override` isn't just mine.  If you take a look at the accepted answer to  [What does @Override mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341432/) mentions that by declaring your intent to *override* a method, you will get warnings if there isn't such a method to override (as in this case).

Comment: you are right @Joshoua.that was a silly mistake I think I could never find out.I fix it and works well,Thank you so much.

Comment: @MD No problem, mona. Be sure to use the `@Override` annotation, and you'll avoid this particular kind of problem in the future.