# Find method contents from a method in superclass? (Java/Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, oop

I want to find the contents of the `java.net.ServerSocket` `accept()` method (because I am trying to override it so it returns a different type). Is this possible in Eclipse, or for that matter, in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible in Java. Because, you can not modify the return type of a function you override. The [Java Tutorials Overriding and Hiding Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) says (in part)

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) **and return type** as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

I recommend you use the [`@Override` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341432/what-does-override-mean) to protect yourself from acidentally [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) a method you intend to override.

Comment: For good measure I just changed the return type of the `accept()` method to a class that `extends` `java.net.Socket` and added the `@Override` annotation before the method. Eclipse threw no errors, so does this mean that the overridden method CAN return a class that extends the original return type?